# Different languages in headings

Tags: header-footer

I am using `babel` with `Greek` and `English` languages. I don't use `XeLaTeX`. I have the following configuration for the header:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{10pt}
```

The problem is that I have some title text with both languages and it is not expanding correct in the headers.

Example: `\section{\texorpdfstring{Η Συσκευή \eng{Kinect}}{}}` and the result is `H Συσκευή Κινεςτ`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}

%Fonts
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

%Hyper reference
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}


%headings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{10pt}

%Commands
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\selectlanguage{english}#1\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\gre}[1]{\selectlanguage{greek}#1\selectlanguage{english}}

\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}


\begin{document}

\section{\texorpdfstring{Η Συσκευή \eng{Kinect}}{}}
Δοκιμή

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you turn your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I guess that the right way to change language is `{\selectlanguage{english} }`.

Comment: `{\selectlanguage{english} }` did't work!

Comment: Your code gives the correct output here.

Comment: Yes, but the header is wrong.

Comment: It works for me, too (babel 3.9k), and the headline shows H Συσκευή Kinect. Which version of babel are you using?

Comment: You were right I updated it manually and it worked. I had 3.8.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue solved by updating to the latest release of the relevant packages.